# Why CompletableFuture runAsync doesn't work in my code?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-11, completable-future

I have example code like

```
private Boolean exampleFunc(Long id) {
  Info info= new Info();
  info.setCustomerId(100L);
  var res = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> exampleApi.doFunc(info));
  return TRUE;
}
```

In this code, "res" gives

> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@22da05fc[Not completed]

When I add
`ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

"res" gives

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

And I can't debug doFunc(), it doesn't go in method.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Runnable` action has generated `NullPointerException`. You can add error handling callback to the action with `res.handle()`, this one simply prints out the details:

```
res.handle((r, ex) -> {
    System.out.println("handle() result="+r+" exc="+ex);
    if (ex != null)
        ex.printStackTrace();
    return r; 
});
```

Comment: I tried this code and result is "handle() result=null exc=java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: You'll find that your issue is nothing to do with `CompletableFuture.runAsync`, just debug this code: `exampleApi.doFunc(info);`

Comment: I can't debug because it doesn't step into exampleApi.doFunc(info). If I use FeignExceutor, everything works fine. But if I use CompletableFuture.runAsync, returns nullPointer.

Comment: @wonka Look at the stack trace printed by `handle()`, it should give a good clue as the cause of the NPE.

Comment: @wonka when it doesn’t enter `exampleApi.doFunc(…)`, then perhaps `exampleApi` is `null`. But as DuncG said, you should look at the stacktrace; that’s what it is for.